# com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method with ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion() - Sikuli

Tags: java, selenium, sikuli

I am using below sikuli code to make use of sikuli methods like **click** in Selenium,but when control come to **ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion()** line, I observed **com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method** in **'s'** reference and at latst getting another exception that **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Objects.toStringHelper(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/base/Objects$ToStringHelper;** No complier issues everything is fine, below are the jars/libraries used -

1. Java version: 8
2. Selenium version:selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0
3. Sikuli version:sikuli-api-1.0.2-standalone

**Note**: Working fine with **selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0** version,below is the is tha code -

```
    try
    {

        fw=new File(sImagePath);
        // Specify an image as the target to find on the screen

        Target imageTarget = new ImageTarget(fw); 
        imageTarget.setMinScore(0.4);
        // ***** in below line i am getting InvocationException ********
        ScreenRegion s = new DesktopScreenRegion();
        s.wait(imageTarget, waitTime);
        ScreenRegion r = s.find(imageTarget);
        Canvas canvas = new DesktopCanvas();
        canvas.addBox(r).display(1);
        Mouse mouse = new DesktopMouse();
        mouse.click(r.getCenter());
    }
```

Can anyone, please help me to resolve the issue, Thanks

Comment: Please note that what you are using is not the original Sikuli that is available here: "https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX-2014" but a separate project that doesn't look to be active at all. Consider moving to the one I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Eugene,I've downloaded 'sikulixsetup-1.1.1' setup file from https://launchpad.net/sikuli/sikulix/1.1.1
just double click on  'sikulixsetup-1.1.1' to create a 'sikulixapi' this is actually needed for sikuli methods, issue is resolved

Thanks again Eugene